# What should be returned from web service instead of datatable?

Tags: web-services, dataset, .net-2.0, asmx, webmethod

I have created a web service in which i need to return multiple records from a function. For that I used datatable, but found that as it cannot be serialized. So we can't use it. So I used dataset instead of datatable. 
My service is going to be used in PHP. I am not sure that they (PHP developers) will be able to get data from my dataset (returned from my webservice's function) or not.

Please suggest me what I should return. Dataset or is there any other better option available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a serializable class that can represent each record in the data set and then return a collection of that.

Comment: do you mean that i will have to create a class similer to fields of datatable and than create an collection of it and return that object from function? right?

Comment: Yes, so lets say have three columns ID, Name, Address. Create a serializable class with three accessors for that then loop through the dataset and create a new instance of that class and add it to the collection. When you return the collection it will automatically be serialized into xml with the name of the class. If you return an array the container element would be <ArrayOfPerson> or a list would be <ListOfPerson>

Comment: since it is a web service to be used cross platform (by a php client) - would the list work? Arrays i am sure of ..but List is a .NET specific class - so not so sure of that..

Comment: It is all just xml to the client so it does not matter what the returning container is.

Answer (score 2):

Use a cross-platform dataformat like XML or JSON that both worlds (PHP & C#) understand.

Comment: i got you point but, not getting that how to return xml from a function. do you mean i should return a object of xmldocuemnt or any other?. plez provide me more details.