# Why dataTable Name is necessary to be given in webServices

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I wondering why it throws a error whenever i not intended to give name of datable.As we know there are constructor for datable class is overloaded.so If i using parameter less constructor is give the error by the basis of serialization .

---

*Can Someone Explain Me why to use Parametrized one but not default for DataTable .*

Comment: why are you using DataTable on a web-service? that is quite perhaps the least web-service-friendly data metaphor that I could imagine

Comment: @Marc Gravell So what i need to do.

Comment: Ideally, you would just return, say, a `List<Customer>` (or whatever your row represents); a class such as `Customer` (unrelated to `DataTable` etc) can be processed and understood by tools such as standard SOAP services (via either asmx or WCF)

Comment: Ditto. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519603/what-should-be-return-from-web-service-instead-of-datatable as a reference, but don't be afraid to ask your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the name is required for the data table to serialize properly.

Why is this? Well, the exact reason seems to be that the serialization process uses the table name as a key, and specifically, an empty data set is created to import it back in. When the name is **not** present, the part that looks for the table name throws an exception and this is why you see the error you are getting.

You don't have to use the constructor, though, you can set the TableName outside:

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
myTable.TableName = "PleaseDontKillMySerialization";
```

If you are interested, you can look at the contents of the class using [ILSpy](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ilspy&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx&ei=ZPLdTveDHo2SswbXxOHrCA&usg=AFQjCNGQwkNS1GUMVxPIfyj8K-YW11wBVA&sig2=l3c8pd7hyFOCpLGAzBoDDg11). This way you can see for yourself how the class is created and look at how serialization works for this class.

As Marc mentions, though, using DataTable restricts you to .Net clients only. It's also quite a large object when serialized so more data has to be transferred per request.

Comment: i am new one on Web services.what you suggest me to do

Comment: @Madhav No worries - we all start off somewhere :-) Why don't you raise a new question with the type of data you want to return (explain what's in the data table) and what kind of clients are going to be calling your webservice?

Comment: :) i getting only 5 rows which are integer datatype  form database which i passing to web services.so i think as for the single database  and only limited rows its better to use the data table.

Comment: If each of those rows represent a user, or a product or something, then create a list of User or Product or Something objects, and return IList<Something> to your clients. They'll love you for it as they can see all of the properties, and there is a much stronger data contract than with DataTable.

Comment: one more thing why IDatatable or IList thorws serialization error for web services.

Comment: @Madhav Sorry, I meant just List or even an array of Something[]

Comment: @Madhav - my Typo - see http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/105767/xmlserializer-cant-serialize-properties-of-type-ilist-t for the underlying reason.